# How to swap months and days in a datetime object?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I have a columns in a pandas dataframe with dates as:

year, day, month , hour , minute, second

```
2015-09-03 14:32:00
```

I would like to turn this into

year, month, day, hour , minute, second

```
2015-03-09 14:32:00
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas.Series.apply) a lambda to your dates and call [`datetime.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

```
In [168]:
# create sample df
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2015-09-03 14:32:00']})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df

Out[168]:
                 date
0 2015-09-03 14:32:00

In [171]:
import datetime as dt
# apply strftime
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strftime(x, '%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S'))
df

Out[171]:
                  date
0  2015-03-09 14:32:00
```

Comment: I tried on my df and I got: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'datetime'

Comment: got I had to import datetime

Comment: Yes I updated my code sample to add line `import datetime as dt`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the python built-in datetime module for conversion:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime("2015-09-03 14:32:00", "%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 0):

You swap month with day from this 2019-22-02 to 2019-02-22 If you have only date with:

pd.to_datetime("2019-22-02", yearfirst=True, dayfirst=False, format='%Y-%d-%m')

you might replace the date "2019-22-02" with your df date column.