# How to clean up datetime strings in dataframe after export from excel sheet?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have an excel spreadsheet with some datetime data in a column. I exported the data into a dataframe using pandas. This column however has chunks of dates that have the month and day swapped, while there are other chunks of dates in the same column that are correct. Here's an example -

[image]

Figure 1: Day and month have been swapped incorrectly

The above picture shows the day and month swapped. The date shows `2016-01-10` but should instead be `2016-10-01`. Compare this with another chunk of datetime values in the same column -

[image]

Figure 2: Day and month are correctly represented

In the above case in Figure 2, the month correctly represented as `12` and the day is `31`.

I used the solution from this question - [How to swap months and days in a datetime object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32253798/how-to-swap-months-and-days-in-a-datetime-object)

I also tried using this solution -
[Python Pandas - Day and Month mix up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41220699/python-pandas-day-and-month-mix-up)

I also tried writing my own function to map to the entries but this was to no avail either -

```
def dm_swap(day, month):
if(month != 10 or month != 11 or month != 12):
    temp = day
    day = month
    month = temp
```

`t2016Q4.start.map(dmswap, t2016Q4.dt.day, t2016Q4.dt.month)`

However, both solutions change all the datetime values in the column. So, when the incorrect values get corrected, the correct values become incorrect.

I've also linked the excel file for your convenience. It's an open data set.

https://www.toronto.ca/city-government/data-research-maps/open-data/open-data-catalogue/#343faeaa-c920-57d6-6a75-969181b6cbde

Please choose the last dataset Bikeshare Ridership (2016 Q4). The "start" and "end" columns have the above mentioned issues.

Is there a more efficient way to clean the datetime data?

Comment: Ah, I see, of course, it's Q4 - carry on without me
I would probably generate a datetime object for 01 october 2016 midnight and 31st december 2016 23:59:59 and compare whether the date objects are in this range using apply. From here, you ought to be able to make the change you need easily enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Andrew observed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53500872/how-to-clean-up-datetime-strings-in-dataframe-after-export-from-excel-sheet/53502032#comment93925937_53501894) that the DataFrame can be fixed by flipping *all* months and days when doing so results in a valid date.

Here's a fast way to "flip" all the dates. Invalid dates are coerced to NaT (Not-A-Timestamp) values and then dropped. The remaining flipped dates can then be reassigned to `df`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('2016_Bike_Share_Toronto_Ridership_Q4.xlsx')

for col in ['trip_start_time', 'trip_stop_time']:
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col])
    swapped = pd.to_datetime({'year':df[col].dt.year, 
                              'month':df[col].dt.day, 
                              'day':df[col].dt.month,
                              'hour':df[col].dt.hour,
                              'minute':df[col].dt.minute,
                              'second':df[col].dt.second,}, errors='coerce')
    swapped = swapped.dropna()
    mask = swapped.index
    df.loc[mask, col] = swapped

# check that now all dates are in 2016Q4
for col in ['trip_start_time', 'trip_stop_time']:
    mask = (pd.PeriodIndex(df[col], freq='Q') == '2016Q4')
    assert mask.all()

# check that `trip_start_times` are in chronological order
assert (df['trip_start_time'].diff().dropna() >= pd.Timedelta(0)).all()

# check that `trip_stop_times` are always greater than `trip_start_times`
assert ((df['trip_stop_time']-df['trip_start_time']).dropna() >= pd.Timedelta(0)).all()
```

The assert statements above verify that the resultant dates are all in 2016Q4, that `trip_start_times` are in chronological order, and that the `trip_stop_times` are always greater than their associated `trip_start_times`.

Comment: After slight modification of this method, I was able to fit everything within Q4. Thank you!

Comment: Might this create an issue with 11/10 or 10/11 which are both in Q4?

Comment: @Andrew: That's an excellent point (that I had totally overlooked). Perhaps a different approach is needed to really solve this problem....

Comment: @ragzputin: The current code is definitely wrong. Look at, for example, the row with `trip_id` equal to 608907. The start date is `2016-11-09` but the end date is `2016-10-11`.

Comment: @ragzputin: I've completely rewritten the code to address the problem Andrew points out. I've also added some more assert statements to test the reasonableness of the result. Please beware that since we're dealing with ambiguous data there's no guarantee that the result above is absolutely correct.

Comment: @unutbu and Andrew thank you so much for taking a deeper look into this! I will try these changes out and see where I get with it.

Answer (score 1):

OK.

EDIT -again. I ran the code below, and it took forever! I aborted in the end, but this definitely works in sensible time as well - good luck!:

```
import pandas as pd

f = "string\to\file\here.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(f)

def alter_date(timestamp):

    try:
        date_time = timestamp.to_datetime().strftime("%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S")
        time_stamp = pd.Timestamp(date_time)
        return time_stamp
    except:
        return timestamp

new_starts = df["trip_start_time"].apply(alter_date)
df["trip_start_time"] = new_starts
new_ends =  df["trip_stop_time"].apply(alter_date)
df["trip_stop_time"] = new_ends
```

EDIT: I had a bit of a dig, and it looks possible based on what I've done previously, new code here:

```
import pandas as pd

f = "string\to\file\here.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(f)

for idx in df.index:
    trip_start = df.loc[df.index[idx], "trip_start_time"]
    trip_end = df.loc[df.index[idx], "trip_stop_time"]
    start_dt = trip_start.to_datetime()
    end_dt = trip_end.to_datetime()
    try:
        start_dt_string = start_dt.strftime("%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S")
        end_dt_string = end_dt.strftime("%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S")
        start_ts = pd.Timestamp(start_dt_string)
        end_ts = pd.Timestamp(end_dt_string)
        df.loc[idx, "trip_start_time"] = start_ts
        df.loc[idx, "trip_stop_time"] = end_ts
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

It's a bit slow (there's a bunch of rows of data) but my computer seems to be working through it - will update again if it fails.

Old response:
So, what's happened is that every date/time where there is no possibility of ambiguity is in the original dataset in the format: DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS.

If it's possible to co-erce to MM/DD/YY HH:MM:SS then it has

What I would do, is to iterate over each column

```
for row in df.index:
    try:
        new_dt = datetime.strptime(row, "%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S")
        #write back to the df here
    except ValueError:
        pass#ignore anything  that cannot be converted
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work for me. The trip_start_time column remained the same with incorrect values. Thank you for your solution! I will experiment with it further.

Comment: This code doesn't actually write back to the original dataframe, which is why yours is unchanged (as I've indicated in the commented line). I would suggest that you either keep track of the index and iterate over that to allow you to overwrite in place or to construct a parallel Series and then add something to the except to preserve correct values then broadcast over the top

Comment: Once you parse the data with `df = pd.read_excel(f)` some of the rows will have the date correctly parsed, and some will have the month and day incorrectly flipped. The problem can't be corrected by calling `alter_date` on every date. We need some criterion to decide which dates are incorrect and only call `alter_date` on those.

Comment: From what I can make out, the dates that are flipped are the ones that are possible to flip, hence my approach. All the instances where there's no ambiguity (i.e. the day is > 12) look to have one format, and all dates where the day is 12 or less seem to have another. `alter_date` tries to switch the day and month, and if it can't makes no change. Happy to be told that this doesn't work for the whole dataset though, if that's the case

Comment: My goodness. Somehow, this possibility never even occurred to me.  Well, [here's
a faster way to swap all months and days](https://gist.github.com/unutbu/efe6000b1eae4b51c6f9035203772f5e). Unswappable dates are coerced to `NaT` (not-a-timestamp) values, then dropped. It produces the same result as my answer, but feels cleaner. Since its based on your observation, you're welcome to use the code in your answer if you like.

Comment: @unutbu That's a really neat solution, and tested formally too - I really like your implementation and I really really need to learn my way around the `assert` keyword :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parameter `format` in `pd.to_datetime`:

```
>>> date= pd.Series(['2016-01-10', '2016-02-10'])
>>> pd.to_datetime(date, format='%Y-%d-%m')
Out: 
0   2016-10-01
1   2016-10-02
```